# Is there any Protractor HTTP Mock library available for non angular applications?

Tags: mocking, protractor

Protractor-http-mock requires angular synchronization so this library can not be used to mock protractor tests for non-angular applications. Can anyone suggest which library will be a best suite to mock non-angular (REACT) application with protractor?

Answer (score 1):

There is a protractor plugin called ng-apimock. The ng here does not stand for angular. This is a generic npm package that can be used as a mock server for testing. Protractor offers the plugin that can be configured and used with ng-apimock to create API mocks for non angular applications. Here is the link for you to check it out:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-apimock

Comment: Can you share some sample code to use ng-apimock with protractor for non angular applications.

Comment: I had worked on it a long time back. Try to implement it yourself it's not that difficult.